# how to quick insert big collection to mysql use waterline

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline

I wanna insert 10000+ records to mysql, If I process 30000+, application is crash

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I use sails 0.10.5,sails-mysql 0.10.8, Model.create([....]).exec();

how to reslove is?

Comment: Can't you just break records into chunks (IE. 1000 records a chunk) and insert them one chunk at a time?

Comment: Yes, So I use Model.query(sqlstr) to insert 30000+ records,split 1000 records a chunk. it's perfect. XD